# Yahoo sub accounts with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap, yahoo-mail

I hava an account on Yahoo (eg. myname@yahoo.com) with several sub accounts (sub1@myname.com, sub2@myname.com)

I am trying to access these accounts using thunderbird with no success.

Have tried:

1. Adding multiple identities to the myname@yahoo account in Thunderbird.
   Thunderbird finds only the main account mails.
2. Added a separate account sub1@myname.com
   Since myname.com is really just a front to Yahoo, this times out.
3. sub1@myname.com@yahoo.com
   Times out.

How do I actually get the mail?
The account is with Yahoo Plus, I can use POP or IMAP,
I have checked and POP access is enabled in options for both the main and sub accounts.

Comment: Have you tried using IMAP ?, this can read the folders in your account where as pop just downloads the mail

Comment: I am using IMAP

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "sub accounts". From an email, my first guess is that they are unique accounts, just related in Yahoo's system, but with no such relation in your mail client.